# Structural pattern matching of lxml HtmlElement attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, python-3.11, structural-pattern-matching

I want to use [PEP 634 – Structural Pattern Matching](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/) to match an [`HtmlElement`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlElement-class.html) that has a particular attribute. The attributes are accessible through an `.attrib` attribute that returns an instance of the [`_Attrib`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Attrib-class.html) class, and IIUC it has all methods for it to be a `collections.abc.Mapping`.

The PEP says this:

> For a mapping pattern to succeed the subject must be a mapping, where being a mapping is defined as its class being one of the following:
>
> - a class that inherits from `collections.abc.Mapping`
> - a Python class that has been registered as a `collections.abc.Mapping`
> - ...

Here's what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't print the `href`:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
from lxml.html import HtmlElement, fromstring
el = fromstring('<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>')
Mapping.register(type(el.attrib))  # lxml.etree._Attrib
assert(isinstance(el.attrib, Mapping))  # It's True even before registering _Attrib.

match el:
    case HtmlElement(tag='a', attrib={'href': href}):
        print(href)
```

This matches and prints `attrib`:

```py
match el:
    case HtmlElement(tag='a', attrib=Mapping() as attrib):
        print(attrib)
```

This does not match, as expected:

```py
match el:
    case HtmlElement(tag='a', attrib=list() as attrib):
        print(attrib)
```

I also tried this and it works:

```py
class Upperer:
    def __getitem__(self, key): return key.upper()
    def __len__(self): return 1
    def get(self, key, default): return self[key]
Mapping.register(Upperer)  # It doesn't work without this line.
match Upperer():
    case {'href': href}:
        print(href)  # Prints "HREF"
```

I understand using XPath/CSS selectors would be easier, but at this point I just want to know what is the problem with the `_Attrib` class and my code.

Also, I don't want to unpack the element and convert the `_Attrib` instance to dict as follows:

```py
match el.tag, dict(el.attrib):
    case 'a', {'href': href}:
        print(href)
```

or use guards:

```py
match el:
    case HtmlElement(tag='a', attrib=attrs) if 'href' in attrs:
        print(attrs['href'])
```

It works but it doesn't look right. I'd like to find a solution so the original `case HtmlElement(tag='a', attrib={'href': href})` works. Or something that's very close to it.

Python version I'm using is 3.11.4.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with Python's use of `match case` to compare two objects for equality, since pattern matching with match case statements is typically used to match different values, not to compare objects for equality. In Python, the `==` operator is often used to compare objects for equality. If you want to compare two objects for equality, you should use `==` instead of `match case`.

Write a class for comparison:

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self,data : HtmlElement= None,**kwargs):
        if not kwargs:
            temp={'tag': data.tag, 'text': data.text,'tail': data.tail,'attrib': data.attrib}
            self.__dict__ = {i:temp[i] for i in temp if temp[i]}
            return
        self.__dict__ =kwargs
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

Use if statement to determine if they are equal

```py
if Element(el) == Element(tag='a',text= 'StackOverflow', attrib={'href': 'https://stackoverflow.com/'}):
    print('equal')
```